# How to get vim to open multiple files into tabs at once

Tags: vim, tabs, gvim

Is it possible to get vim to open multiple files into tabs, similar to the way the `args <path>` command will open multiple files into buffers?

Doing something like `:tabe ./*` results in the error "E77: Too many file names", even though the number of files is less than the value set in the `tabpagemax` property.

(I believe the `vim -p <files>` option will open in tabs, but I'm hoping to find a way to do it when vim is already open.)

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the -p option; that's what I was looking for

Comment: I found this question via Google.  I was looking for how to open vim with tabs from the command line, `vim -p` was what I was looking for :-)

Comment: Related: [How can I open multiple tabs at once?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2108/how-can-i-open-multiple-tabs-at-once) at Vim SE

Comment: Related: [Open several files in new tabs with VIM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430361/open-several-files-in-new-tabs-with-vim) at Stack Overflow.

Comment: Related: [How to open many tabs for many files in vim?](http://superuser.com/questions/378429/vim-open-many-tabs-for-many-files) at Super User.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

```
:tab all
```

will open all the files in Vim's argument list in individual tabs. The argument list is initially set to the list of file names given on the command line when Vim is started. The list may be changed with the `:args` and related commands. See

```
:help :all
:help argument-list
```

Example:

```
:args *.c
:tab all
```

will open all the .c files in the current directory in individual tabs.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is meant to work. Say if I want to open all .txt files in the current directory, what would I enter? If I enter `:tab all *.txt`, vim counters with "E488: Trailing characters"

Comment: I edited the answer to clarify what I meant by "arguments". I meant Vim's argument list rather than arguments to `:tab all`.

Comment: Nice, got it now. The only thing that could make this better is a one line equivalent...what do you think the chances are?

Comment: I don't know of a single command that can do that, but you can put two commands on one line by separating them with a vertical bar, like this: `:args *.c | tab all`.

Comment: The downside is that using `:tab all` replaces your existing tabs. Because of this, in my use case, it doesn't provide much benefit over reopening files with `vim -p`. However, if there were some way to stuff existing tabs into `:args`, it might be possible to open new tabs and keep the existing ones.

Comment: This worked great for me. I wanted to open all files in my directory with the same extension. This did the trick. Thanks so much.

Comment: If a tab is already open, substitute `argadd` for `args`.

Comment: This is great. It also works from the command line. If you do `vim *` in bash, then `:tab all` in vim, you can open all the contents of a directory in separate tabs.

Comment: Does this work on neovim? In my case this only works on vim...

Answer (score 11):

You actually can open new tabs and keep your current tabs without writing new functions. See this answer on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11430615/200234

```
:args file1 file2 | argdo tabe
```

You may want to open a new empty tab (`:tabe`) before doing that, because the first file will open in the current tab. Also, an extra empty tab will be left open (see `:help argdo` to understand why).

Comment: If you're adding new tabs to an existing set, wouldn't it be easier just to `:tabe file1`?

Comment: @jpaugh, the question is about multiple files.

Comment: Wouldn't `:args | argdo tabe` answer the question, though? What's the reason for adding new files this way?

Comment: @jpaugh, this is what the question asks for: "I believe the vim -p <files> option will open in tabs, but I'm hoping to find a way to do it when vim is already open."

Comment: This did what I needed! I used a wildcard `:args *.c | argdo tabe`
With the top answer it was opening some files in windows and some in tabs, but this opens all of them in tabs.

Answer (score 3):

To open files in new tabs without replacing the arguments or tabs that are already open:

```
:argadd *.c | tab all
```

This was mentioned in a comment but I think deserves its own answer.

Also, to search for files in subdirectories:

```
:argadd code/**/*.c | tab all
```

Answer (score 1):

I mapped @Mihai Capotă soltuion, adding an automatic change directory to current file. Add this line to $HOME/.vimrc file:

```
nnoremap <C-S-t> :cd<Space>%:p:h<CR>:tabe<CR>:args<Space>*.html<Space>\|<Space>argdo<Space>tabe<Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left>
```

Code explanation:

```
<C-S-t>
```

map to Crtrl-Shit-T (like FireFox is Ctrl-T for new tab)

```
:cd<Space>%:p:h<CR>
```

change directory to the one in current file open in VIM, read:
https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Set_working_directory_to_the_current_file

```
:tabe<CR>
```

read @Mihai Capotă soltuion

```
:args<Space>*.html<Space>\|<Space>argdo<Space>tabe
```

read same

```
<Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left>
```

move cursor to asterisk

To improve:

1. the current tap will be a blank (just close it Ctrl-W-q or :q). Ideally this tab should be autoclosed (also from buffer).
2. go to previous tap may be easy if you remember it, e.g. if it was 1st tab then just press 1gt or :tabr. Ideally this go to previous should be automatic.

PD: it might be a comment, not a solution, if so, then please comment it, I cannot.