# How to open many tabs for many files in vim?

Tags: vim, tabs

I can open one file in a new tab with:

```
:tabnew file
```

Let's say I have many files, for example: util.h and util.cpp.

How I can open those files all in separate, new tabs?

I'm looking for something similar to

```
:tabnew util.*
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, add the files as arguments:

```
:argadd util.*
```

Then use the `:argdo` command with `:tabnew`:

```
:argdo tabnew
```

You could do this with `:bufadd` and `:bufdo` but none of the buffer commands can add multiple files at the same time.  Also, using the `:argadd` method may avoid opening tabs for files you already have open—it depends on whether you invoked Vim with multiple file arguments, or whether you have already been using the `:arg*` commands.  (You could always do `:argdel *` first.)