# Open multiple additional tabs at once within Vi

Tags: vim

I often switch back and forth between multiple files at once in vi and am always adding more with `tabe`. Is there a way to add more than one tab at the same time while keeping all my open tabs?

I've tried the obvious `tabe *.php` but apparently `tabe` only takes one file because that yields a `too many arguments` error.  I've also tried adding the files to args and then opening args with `tab all` as per [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/171763/how-to-get-vim-to-open-multiple-files-into-tabs-at-once) but that closes my open tabs (probably because I'm overwriting args). I guess what I'm trying to do is append file names to args. Anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Related: [How can I open multiple tabs at once?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2108/how-can-i-open-multiple-tabs-at-once) at Vim SE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add all your `*.php` files to the argument list:

   ```
   :args *.php
   ```
2. Move each item in the argument list to a new tab:

   ```
   :argdo tabe
   ```

But you should think again about your use of tabs: buffers are a vastly simpler metaphor.

Comment: I tried this. It still close my open tab.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to mess with args define function

```
fu! OpenTabs( pattern )
    let list = split(expand(a:pattern), '\n')
    call map(list, "'tabe ' . v:val")
    for c in list | exe c | endfor
endf
```

For instance to edit all your rc files in tabs do:

```
:call OpenTabs( '.*rc' )
```

Other then that you could use `argadd` so your current list is not replaced.

Answer (score 0):

I would echo what @romainl said: you should try getting used to buffers instead (I was in exactly the same position as you were about six months ago, and now I almost never use tabs).

That said:

```
:tab ball
```

will open all existing buffers (files that you're editing) in separate tabs. So you could use:

```
:e *.php
:tab ball
```

See `:h ball` and `:h tab` within vim.

Comment: `:e` and related commands like `:tabedit` or `:split` don't take more than one argument, that's why we must populate the arglist first. `:ball` is cool, though.

Answer (score 0):

Using [CtrlP](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim) plugin you can select multiple files matching a specific search.

After you entered your search use `<C-j>` and `<C-k>` (or arrows) to move in the result list and `<C-z>` to select/unselect a file.
Then use `<C-t>` to open your selection in tabs.