# Why does `:tab all` open most files in new tabs and some in a one tab split horizontally?

Tags: vim, tabs

I want to open all the files from the current directory matching *.c.

I do it using

```
:args *.c
:tab all
```

However my vim opens the first nine files in new tabs and the last six in the last tab and splits them horizontally.

I've tried to use commands like `:tabnew` instead of `:tab` but they require a single file - I don't know how to solve my problem using those.

My questions are:

- How can I quickly open many files the way every file has its own tab? Maybe it is possible to disable splitting?
- Why does `:tab` behaves this way?

[image: Multiple files in one tab]

Comment: It looks like you are misusing tab pages. Use buffers instead.

Comment: `:h 'tabpagemax'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there is a way to do it according to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/894326/442991):

```
:args *.c | argdo tabe
```

Works perfectly. It will probably close all your other tabs though. Click [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2108/how-can-i-open-multiple-tabs-at-once) if you want to learn more.

When it comes to the weird behaviour of `:tab` it turns out that there is a variable `tabpagemax` which is set to 10 by default (see `:h tabepagemax`). This explains everything.

You can find out what is the value of variables in vim using `:set foo?` where *foo* is the variable you are looking for.

Here are some references I've come by:

- [How can I open multiple tabs at once?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2108/how-can-i-open-multiple-tabs-at-once)
- [Vim tips: Using tabs](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/442422-vim-tips-using-tabs)